# Set field level security on a Home item in sitecore

Tags: security, sitecore, field, readonly

I have a question about setting security for a couple of fields for the Home item in sitecore.

I have a template, let's called it TaggingTemplate with 7 fields, let's call them - field1, field2, field3... field7.
This template is being used by all other templates in my sitecore structure.

The Home item which uses "Home" template inherits "TaggingTemplate" as well.

What I want to do is set fields - field1 through field5 as read-only for everyone except Administrator for the Home item. How can I do that?
There are a bunch of security settings set on the home item and any change in the security settings for the home item can affect the entire website.

I couldn't set that security setting in Home template since field1-field5 are inherited from TaggingTemplate.
I couldn't find a way to do that through security editor as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. They are really helpful. I have decided to make a copy of the template and then inherit that on the Home item instead of writing the code and everything.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot see inherited fields via a template in the Security Editor. So, you can use the Security Editor to restrict access to certain fields on the `TaggingTemplate` for all instances of that template, but you cannot restrict access only when the `TaggingTemplate` is inherited by template `Home`.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark mentions in his answer, there's no way to do this with Sitecore security. You could prevent it with a SaveUI pipeline plugin, albeit in not the most user-friendly manner.

Use a tool such as ILSpy to examine pipeline processors in `Sitecore.Pipelines.Save`. Create a processor with a `Process(SaveArgs args)` method. If `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAdministrator`, you can do an early return. Otherwise, examine the collection args.Items and the fields within each `SaveArgs.SaveItem` to determine if it's the home item, and if one of your fields in question has been edited. If so, use the following logic to stop the save and alert the user:

```
protected void AbortSave(SaveArgs args)
    {
        if (args.HasSheerUI)
        {
            SheerResponse.Alert("You cannot edit these fields.");
            SheerResponse.SetReturnValue("failed");
        }
        args.AbortPipeline();
    }
```

Your alternative is to refactor your templates to move these fields to another item which the user cannot edit.